# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой Call to a member function getActiveSheet() on null

Tags: php, phpexcel

Возможно вопрос глупый, но, видимо глаз уже замылился и не вижу очевидного. При работе с классом возникла такая ошибка: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getActiveSheet() on null in C:\OSPanel\domains\projectOKK\includes\tablehandler.inc.php:320`

Вот сам код tablehandler:

```
class TableHandler extends Dbh {

public function exportSupport($from){
$operator = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connect(), $from);

         $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();// Создаем объект класса PHPExcel
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();// Получаем активный лист
            $sheet->setTitle(''.$operator.''); // Подписываем лист

//Функция для покраски ячеек со строки 320
        function cellColor($cells,$color){
            global $objPHPExcel;

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'startcolor' => array(
                    'rgb' => $color
                )
            ));
        }
        cellColor('A2', 'c6d6b0');
    }

    }
```

Возможно какая-то ошибка в области видимости, но я уже не знаю, что делать) Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и первый ответ, есть еще способ более простой, чтобы Вам не переписывать структуру класса. Использовать анонимную функцию, передав ей необходимый объект в качестве замыкания тем самым избегая использование глобальных переменных. Пример:

```
$cellColor = function($cells,$color) use ($objPHPExcel){
    //Ваш код
}
$cellColor('A2', 'c6d6b0');
```

Comment: `$objPHPExcel` будет по-прежнему не определена. [Пруф](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6daccf64fceb1a60901c631fd2f6fa3fd615d973)

Comment: @Jigius я полагаю, автор предложил сделать так [ссылка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28c2703b4e19b9a8f1d03ebcba6cb29d55ed67bf)   Сейчас гляну в своем коде и отпишусь)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Кому интересно - вот код [ссылка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e307080808839a93d0123579d8009a2e2571ff9)

Comment: @Glechik рад что помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Метод `cellColor()` **не видит переменную** `$objPHPExcel` в локальной и глобальной областей видимости.

Можно решить проблему так: в метод `exportSupport()` добавить `global $objPHPExcel;`.

Но я противник "замусоривания" глобальной области и предлагаю в методе `exportSupport()` значение переменной `$objPHPExcel` присвоить  свойству объекта и его уже использовать в методе `cellColor()`:

```
class TableHandler extends Dbh {
    private objPHPExcel;

    public function exportSupport($from)
    {
        ...
        $this->objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel;
    {

    public function cellColor($cells,$color)
    {
        $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-> ...
    }  
}
```

После исправления проблемы с областью видимости `$objPHPExcel` у вас может возникнуть **еще одна** проблема:

Метод `cellColor()` "завязан" на уже проинициализированный объект св-ва `objPHPExcel` и должен вызываться *ПОСЛЕ* метода `exportSupport()`. Это, так называемое, связывание(coupling) решается перепроектированием объекта, но это не предмет вашего вопроса.